# Shaders with Typescript and React three fiber

Tags: typescript, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to use shaders with React-three-fiber and Typescript.
Shader file:

```
import { ShaderMaterial } from "three"
import { extend } from "react-three-fiber"

class CustomMaterial extends ShaderMaterial {
  constructor() {
    super({
      vertexShader: `...`,
      fragmentShader: `...`,
      uniforms: [...]
    })
  }
}

extend({ CustomMaterial })
```

and the component file:

```
<mesh
  key={el.name}
  material={el.material}
  receiveShadow
  castShadow
>
  <bufferGeometry attach="geometry" {...el.geometry} />
  <customMaterial attach="material" />
</mesh>
```

I'm getting error:

> Property 'customMaterial' does not exist on type
> 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      customMaterial: ReactThreeFiber.Object3DNode<CustomMaterial, typeof CustomMaterial>
    }
  }
}
```

You might also need to stick in the following in your imports:

```
import { extend } from 'react-three-fiber'
...
extend ({ CustomMaterial })
```

Comment: sorry for digging up an old thread, but im stuck on this same issue.. Where do I put this declare global ?

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Would just like to add that if you're trying to add something other than a custom material, you can use ReactThreeFiber.Object3DNode.

I was trying to get OrbitControls to work, and managed to do it with the following method:

```tsx
import { extend } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';

declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface Intrinsicelements {
            orbitControls: ReactThreeFiber.Node<OrbitControls, typeof OrbitControls>;
        }
    }
}

extend({ OrbitControls });
```